# React select requires double click for collapsing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-select

i have react-select components which i made compatible with redux form like this code:

```
const MySelect = props => (
  <div>
    <Select
      {...props}
      value={props.input.value ? props.input.value : 'All'}
      onChange={value => props.input.onChange(value)}
      // onFocus={() => props.input.onFocus(props.input.value)}
      onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
      options={props.options}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      selectedValue={props.selectedValue}
    />
    {
      props.meta.touched && props.meta.error &&
      <span className="error">
        { props.intl.formatMessage({ id: props.meta.error }) }
      </span>
    }
  </div>
);
```

It is working fine except from one thing. It requires two clicks for collapsing. Why is this happening?